# A question from hoffman y kunze. About Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a projection $E$ wich projects $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto the subspace spanned by $(1,-1)$ along the subspace spanned by $(1,2)$.

What is the way to approach this problem? Almost to start!

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- $E(1,-1)=(1,-1)=1\cdot(1,-1)$
- $E(1,2)=(0,0)=0\cdot(1,2)$

Comment: Projecting "along" a specified vector space means that all vectors in that particular space is in the kernel of the projection operator. Think of projecting onto the x-axis, along the y-axis. What happens to the y-component?

Comment: Ah nevermind I misread the question.  Good hints, +1.

Comment: ok! np, i also tend to misread - I think it's a good thing if we can "think aloud" on this site...

Answer (score 1):

(Refer to Christiaan's answer.)

**Additional hints:**

- A projection should be a linear map.
- $(1,2)$ and $(1 -1)$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$.